# Is there a way to log the queries executed by a Oracle UCP?

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat8, ojdbc, ucp

I have a Oracle UCP connection Pool responsible for executing queries from the  Java application. I want to see all the  queries in the logs that this UCP takes care of.

I followed this guide https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/dgn_conpool.htm#CIHIGBIJ to use the property of `'oracle.ucp.level'` to set the log level to FINEST.

I couldnt see the sql queries in logs. I could see all other information like getting a connection, DB URL etc in the logs but I couldnt see the SELECT query that was executed by this connection pool.

Is there a way we could see the SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE queries executed by the Oracle UCP ?

If not the whole query , Atleast can we see whether it is a SELECT or INSERT or UPDATE ?

Comment: which version of the connection pool are you using?

Comment: I am using ucp 12.1.0.2

Comment: It looks like what you want is to turn on logging in the JDBC driver (not UCP) where the query execution will happen.

Comment: Yup realized that. It needs special ojdbc debugging jar to achieve that.